# Too high screen (android)

Tags: android, height, screen

Does anybody know why my layout is seen like [this](http://i47.tinypic.com/2012h3m.png)?

All the elements are layout_height="wrap_content"...

I don't know why, if I add the scrollview, I have to see all the white space down there.

```
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="466dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fondo"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/generandoDemandaTitulo"
            tools:context=".GenerandoDemanda" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTitulo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:ignore="TextFields" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/generandoDemandaDescripcion"
            tools:context=".GenerandoDemanda" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextDescripcion"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:ignore="TextFields" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textoAmbito"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/generandoDemandaAmbito" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/botonSeleccionarAmbito"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/generandoDemandaBotonAmbito"
                android:onClick="showMenuAmbito" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/generandoDemandaDesde" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="showDatePickerDialogDesde"
                android:text="@string/eligeFecha" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fechaDesde"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/horaDesde"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
            android:text="@string/generandoDemandaHasta" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="showDatePickerDialogHasta"
                android:text="@string/eligeFecha" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fechaHasta"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/horaHasta"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/generandoDemandaPrecio" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                android:text="@string/generandoDemandaBotonZona" >
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/generandoDemandaPublica" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textOff="Publico"
                android:textOn="Privado" />
    </LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/clearcache"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/generandoDemandaBotonCrear" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

So, can anybody help me? Where can be the error or something.

Comment: why linear layout_height=466 dp??? give it wrap_content and try it...

Comment: This is an Eclipse screenshot, does your layout look ok in the emulator? What's the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my LinearLayout inside the parent ScrollView. Before adding the ScrollView I had as background an image. Putting the background of the ScrollView and not in the LinearLayout has solved it.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="466dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="466dp"
                               ^^^^^
        android:background="@drawable/fondo"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

You provide `466 dp` height replace it with `wrap_content`.

Comment: i check it its true. don't set fix height. set wrap_content

Comment: ya its seems to regular in xml view not as your reference image .

Comment: Sorry, I manually changed height to that pixels but it wasn't get solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:background="@drawable/backgroundlogin">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```